# Are PreLU and Leaky ReLU better than ReLU in the case of noisy labels?

Tags: machine-learning, activation-functions, relu

Let's assume I want to build a semantic segmentation algorithm, based on Multires-UNET. My GT-masks are messy and generated by a GAN, but they are getting better and better over time. The goal is knowledge expansion (based on the paper [Noisy-Student](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.04252)).

Can you generally say that PreLU and Leaky Relu are better for noisy labels (or imperfect ones), like the situation in GANs in general?

Comment: To my experience ReLU is superior to LeakyReLU.

Answer (score 0):

The provably more-reliable approach to learning with noisy labels/label errors (instead of altering the model architecture or loss function) is to find the label errors and train without them on cleaned data -- a result shown in the [confident learning paper (Northcutt, Lu, Chuang; 2021)](https://cleanlab.ai/studio)). I am an author on this paper.

Re-phrasing your question to two questions: (1) "how can I generally find label errors in any dataset for any model?" and (2) "how can I train a model on noisy data as if it was clean data?".

There are one line of code answers to each of these questions using the [cleanlab](https://docs.cleanlab.ai) python package which implements the algorithms and theory in the confident learning paper and works for **any dataset you can train a classifier on** for most data formats, ML and deep learning frameworks, and data modalities, e.g. image, text, tabular, and audio data.

link to python package: https://github.com/cleanlab/cleanlab

### Find label issues in 1 line of code

```
from cleanlab.classification import CleanLearning
from cleanlab.filter import find_label_issues

# Option 1 - works with sklearn-compatible models - just input the data and labels ツ
label_issues_info = CleanLearning(clf=sklearn_compatible_model).find_label_issues(data, labels)

# Option 2 - works with ANY ML model - just input the model's predicted probabilities
ordered_label_issues = find_label_issues(
    labels=labels,
    pred_probs=pred_probs,  # out-of-sample predicted probabilities from any model
    return_indices_ranked_by='self_confidence',
)
```

### Train a model as if the dataset did not have errors -- 3 lines of code

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from cleanlab.classification import CleanLearning

cl = CleanLearning(clf=LogisticRegression())  # any sklearn-compatible classifier
cl.fit(train_data, labels)

# Estimate the predictions you would have gotten if you trained without mislabeled data.
predictions = cl.predict(test_data)
```

Documentation and runnable tutorials for cleanlab: https://docs.cleanlab.ai/